# Constants in function prototype

Tags: c++

What's the difference between these two C++ function declarations:

```
(1) int Foo(const double x)

(2) int Foo(const double const x)
```

Comment: One has a redundant const, the other doesn't

Comment: Your compiler should tell you which is well-formed and which isn't, once you add the missing `;` to each.

Comment: @Borgleader: In a declaration, both are redundant (although having just one isn't an error).

Comment: The dupe is incorrect...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const double const x;
```

This is redundant for data types. However, had there been pointer it would makes sense.

For e.g:-

```
const double *const x;
```

Here, 'x' is constant pointer to constant double.

whereas

```
const double *x;
```

means 'x' is pointer to constant double. Means you can change the pointer to point to something else.

Comment: If it had been a pointer, e.g. `int Foo(const double* const x)`, what would be the meaning?

Comment: @Karnivaurus: Read from right to left. "Constant pointer to constant double".

Answer (score 0):

The second `const` is completely redundant, another form of the same signature is:

```
(3) int Foo(double x)
```

Comment: No, that would be the same signature. Top-level cv-qualifiers don't affect the signature, since they only affect how the function can treat its local parameters.